# reading a complicated CSV file in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a huge csv file which is something like:

```
0, "24 44 43 51......"
1, "99 81 34 58......"
```

the dots represent more numbers in each line. Each line has a serial number, eg. 0, 1, 2... and corresponding numbers(around 1000). I have more than 1000 lines in this file. Is there any way to read this file in a matrix which consists of the rows and columns like:

```
0 24 44 43 51......(more data)
1 99 81 34 58......(more data)
.
.
.
```

I have tried `tdfread` but gave up as it takes too long to read. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For stuff like this, I find it easier to run the file through python or perl and convert it to a format Matlab is happier with. For example, if you can just make all the numbers comma separated on the line, you can simply `load filename` in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general approach I recommend in such cases:

1. Read the lines (for example, with `textscan`).
2. Replace delimiting characters with spaces (for example, with `regexprep`)
3. Apply `str2num` on each line to extract the numerical values:

Here's sample code:

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '');
C = cellfun(@str2num, regexprep(C{:}, '[",]', ' '), 'UniformOutput', false);
fclose(fid);
```

The result is a cell array of vectors of numbers, one vector per line. If all vectors have the same number of elements, you can convert the cell array to a matrix with:

```
M = vertcat(C{:});
```

#### Alternative solution

If you know the number of values per line in advance (let's denote it `N`), you can use shorter syntax:

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
C = textscan(fid, repmat('%f', 1, N), 'Delimiter', '", \b\t', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true);
fclose(fid);
M = [C{:}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
>> n = 2;    % The number of lines; 1000 in your case.
>> A = textread('test1.txt','%d','delimiter',', "','emptyvalue',0);
>> B = reshape(A,uint64(numel(A)/n),n)';
>> B = B(:,[1, 3:end]);
```

For the input in **test1.txt** as:

```
0, "24 44 43 51"
1, "99 81 34 58"
```

The result was:

```
>> B

B =

     0    24    44    43    51
     1    99    81    34    58
```

Comment: What if the number of linse (`n`) is unknown?

Comment: @EitanT: Well, this wouldn't do; I'd have to work on that. For that matter, I'm also wondering how to handle a variable number of values per line.

Comment: You'll have to store the values in cells then. See my solution :)

Comment: @EitanT: Aah.. Good one. :)